# Average time for approval of iPhone application on Appstore

Tags: iphone, app-store

Any idea on what is the average time that Appstore usually takes to approve/dis-approve a submitted application ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than giving an answer (which will fluctuate greatly at times), [there is a page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) where Apple publishes the percentage of both new and updated apps that are approved within 7 days.  They update this on a semi-regular basis and can give you a general feel for how long it will take.  I have seen this as high as the mid-to-high 90s and as low as the 80s.  It all depends on a number of factors, like the complexity of your application, how many others are in the queue at the time, is it close to a new release of iOS, and how grumpy SJ is feeling (just kidding about that one).

**UPDATE**:

Another great resource is [this site](https://appreviewtimes.com/) from ShinyDevelopment.  They crowd source their data from developers and can give a better idea on how long things are taking--something especially useful when Apple doesn't update their site regularly.

Comment: The Apple page referenced no longer shows this information, and that updated link is also broken.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give out some updated info. 7 day Waiting for Review, 7 hours in Review, Ready for Sale end of 7th day.

Answer (score 1):

There are also sites like http://148apps.biz/app-store-metrics/?mpage=approval that try to measure what the current average approval time is.

Also note the "max delay" column...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I can tell you about the App I have developed:
It got disapproved after 3 days because of a naming inconsistency. After fixing that and submitting the app again it was approved after 5 days. Apple itself says that 90% of all submitted apps are reviewed within 7 days.

Comment: what they meant with naming inconsistency?

Answer (score -1):

95% of the apps get approved in 7 days after submitting the to the app store.

Comment: They have variable stats in developer portal.